# Why DX12 use the bad naming like ID3D12XXX, ID3D12XXX1, ID3D12XXXN?

Tags: directx, naming

IMHO I think these naming convention is bad because they doesn't tell you the difference between each other and make people hard to remember the which is the right one to use.

PS: related page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/

Answer (score 0):

Without discussing what we do prefer as naming conventions as it would be off topic, I'll try to explain the reasons behind that design choice.

This number is the version of the structure/function in the order it appeared in the API as new features were added, so it is easier to keep track of the version of the API that goes with the function.

In a perfect world their would be only one function/structure as these XXXN functions are just extensions of the previous one, but that is not possible considering the continuous development of rendering technologies.

There are other approaches though as you can see in Vulkan, with an extension possibility checked at runtime via the `VkStructureType` enum, and while it is a great and clear tool for extensions, it has its own downsides as it is more verbose and figured out late at runtime. You may remark though that Vulkan takes the same approach when the functions isn't extensible as with `VkPhysicalDeviceProperties2` for example.